# MapKit: How to retrieve apartment number from the return value of MKLocalSearchResponse

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, mkmapitem, mklocalsearch

I searched thoroughly online but couldn't find any discussion about this:

The MKLocalSearchResponse object returned from a MapKit search is a collection of MKMapItem, which has the information of search results, e.g. City, state, country.

A single MKMapItem looks like this(from Xcode quick look of the object):

```
"Name: ADVANCED SOLUTIONS ADDICTION MANAGEMENT CurrentLocation: 0 Place: <GEOPlace: 0x9b2db90> {
            address =     {
                formattedAddressLine =         (
                    \"205 W Crestway Ave\",
                    \"Unit 200\",
                    \"Derby, KS  67037-1850\",
                    \"United States\"
                );
                structuredAddress =         {
                    administrativeArea = Kansas;
                    administrativeAreaCode = KS;
                    country = \"United States\";
                    countryCode = US;
                    dependentLocality =             (
                        Derby,
                        Rockford
                    );
                    fullThoroughfare = \"205 W Crestway Ave\";
                    geoId =             (
                    );
                    locality = Derby;
                    postCode = 67037;
                    postCodeExtension = 1850;
                    postCodeFull = \"67037-1850\";
                    subAdministrativeArea = Sedgwick;
                    subLocality = Rockford;
                    subPremise =             (
                                        {
                            name = 200;
                            type = 0;
                        }
                    );
                    subThoroughfare = 205;
                    thoroughfare = \"W Crestway Ave\";
                };
            };
            }"
```

I was able to retrieve all the information I needed, except the Apartment number. It's contained in the "subPremise" part, which I don't know how to retrieve.

You may suggest me to retrieve it from the "formattedAddressLines", which I have access to, but for some results, that property is empty, so I cannot rely on it.

I've also tried the "addressDictionary" property, it has all the necessary information except apartment number, which is very unthoughtful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mapItem.placemark.subThoroughfare. Note that it may be empty